# Plot data on number line and colour

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have two lists `predictedY` which contains `n` elements ranging from 0 to 1  and `unlabelledY` which contains `n` elements either 1 or 0.

I wish to plot the value of `predictedY` on a number line and if the corresponding element in `unlabeledY` is a 1 to colour it red, otherwise colour it black.

How can I do this?

```
predictedY =[0.456,0.962,0.231]
UnlabelledY=[0,1,0]
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a scatter plot, you can supply `UnlabelledY` as the color argument. Choosing a fitting colormap (in this case e.g. `"hot_r"` with `vmin=-2`) allows to get you the colors of your choice.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

predictedY =[0.456,0.962,0.231] 
UnlabelledY=[0,1,0]

plt.scatter(predictedY, np.zeros_like(predictedY), 
            c=UnlabelledY, cmap="hot_r", vmin=-2)

plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use seaborn library's [`sns.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html). Have a look at `group` attribute of `df`. Rest should follow from comments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# creating dataframe. y is zeros since you want to plot on x-axis. Also len(x) should be equal to len(y)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.array(predictedY),"y":np.zeros(len(predictedY)), "group":np.array(UnlabelledY)})

# fit_reg=False will not draw a horizontal line(which is the regression line)
sns.lmplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="group", fit_reg=False)

plt.ylim(-0.05, 1) # for proper formatting. 
plt.show()
```

[image: It should look like this]